# Mercurial, how to remove file from repository?

Tags: mercurial

I push in our repository more big video files, my fault, I did not notice them and forgot to add the folder with the video to ignore file. Now my friends can not upgrade because a shortage of memory (abort: out of memory). How do I remove a video from the master repository? I tried to just delete the folder with the video in /home/hg/project/.hg/ But then do not start updating with an error. Help me pliz and sorry for my english/

Comment: I was used "strip" and afte thet upload new code.

Answer (score 4):

See the [Mercurial FAQ](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/FAQ):

- [4.14](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/FAQ#FAQ.2FCommonProblems.I_committed_a_change_containing_nuclear_launch_codes.2C_how_do_I_delete_it_permanently.3F). I committed a change containing nuclear launch codes, how do I delete it permanently?
- [4.15](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/FAQ#FAQ.2FCommonProblems.I_committed_a_large_binary_file.2Ffiles_how_do_I_delete_them_permanently.3F). I committed a large binary file/files, how do I delete them permanently?

There are some options described on the [Editing History](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/EditingHistory) page as well.

Answer (score 1):

You:

```
$ hg rm video.ogv
$ hg ci -m "removed video.ogv"
```

Other:

```
$ hg pull your-repository
$ hg update
```

Comment: user@user-PC:/var/www/project$ hg rm project.clone
project.clone: No such file or directory
not removing project.clone: file is untracked
user@user-PC:/var/www/project$

Comment: Why do you try to remove project.clone?

Comment: This is the folder with the project in which a lot of video files. I am her first commit, then removed and again commit.

Comment: Can I described the situation correctly, I created a project with a lot of video files that you commit and push. Then I removed the project again commit and push. After that, I can not remove it from the master repository, remove it, I want to, because for these large video files, one can not be updated.

Comment: Your solution will only create a new changeset which has the file removed - it will still exist as an entity in the repository, which does not solve the problem of memory issues when cloning/pulling.

Answer (score 0):

The HG FAQ merely gives a few vague pointers.  Here's how to do it:

1. Add to your `.hgrc`:

   ```
   [extensions]
   hgext.convert=
   [convert]
   hg.saverev=false
   ```
2. Create a filemap of what files you want to remove (`myfilemap`)

   ```
   exclude "relative/path/to/file.mp4"
   ```
3. Use `hg convert` to make a new repo

   ```
   hg convert --filemap myfilemap myrepo myrepo.new
   ```
4. Now you have the new repo without the excluded files.